# Accessing files saved by android emulator camera app on my laptop

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have written a camera application which records a video and saves the file at address:

`content://media/external/video/media/filename`

I am using Android BlueStacks app player for Windows and I want to know how can I access the recorded files on my laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eclipse click DDMS -> File Explorer -> Find Your PATH! -> Pull a File From Device!

**(Note that ofcourse your emulator should be working..)**

Like :

[image]